# How to Update previous row column based on the current row column data using LinQ

Tags: linq

```
var customer= from cust in customerData
              select new Customer
               {
                 CustomerID = cust["id"],
                 Name = cust["Name"],
                 LastVisit = cust["visit"],
                 PurchashedAmount = cust["amount"],
                 Tagged = cust["tagged"]
                 Code = cust["code"]
               }
```

The rows looks like this

```
Name    LastVisit   PurchasedAmount    Tagged   Code       CustomerID
------  ---------    --------------     ------   -----       -----
Joshua  07-Jan-09                      Yes      chiJan01    A001
Joshua                10000
```

The 2nd row belongs to first row just that the other columns are empty.How can i merge the PurchasedAmount into the first row using LinQ?

Comment: And also delete the 2nd row after merging PurchasedAmount with first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a more general solution than you need - it will work even if the other values are scattered across rows. The main condition is that the `Name` column should identify rows that belong together.

```
customer = from c in customer
           group c by c.Name
           into g
           select new Customer
           {
               Name = g.Key,
               LastVisit = g.Select(te => te.LastVisit).
                             Where(lv => lv.HasValue).FirstOrDefault(),
               PurchaseAmount = g.Select(te => te.PurchaseAmount).
                                  Where(pa => pa.HasValue).FirstOrDefault(),
               Tagged = g.Select(te => te.Tagged).
                          Where(ta => ta.HasValue).FirstOrDefault(),
               Code = g.Select(te => te.Code).
                        Where(co => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(co)).FirstOrDefault(),
               CustomerID = g.Select(te => te.CustomerID).
                        Where(cid => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cid)).FirstOrDefault()

           };
```

This will return a new `IEnumerable` with the items grouped by `Name` and the non-null values selected (same effect as moving PurchasedAmount to the first row and deleting the second in your case).

Note that the code is based on the assumption that `LastVisit`, `PurchaseAmount` and `Tagged` are nullable types (`DateTime?`, `int?` and `bool?`). Thus the usage of `HasValue`. If, however, they are strings in your case, you have to use `!string.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead (as for `Code` and `CustomerID`).